# Is there a way to Group Rows automatically?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel like this:

```
Name       DOC        STATUS
John      ID         OK
John      ADRESS     Incomplete
John      SURNAME    Missing
Lara      ID         OK
Lara      ADRESS     Missing
Lara      SURNAME    Missing
Rony      ID         OK
Rony      ADRESS     OK
Rony      SURNAME    OK
```

The idea is, the names repeat itself 3 times because of each DOC. Is there a way to group rows automatically? Like, group every 3 rows?

Comment: Like, group how? With a border? Merge cells? In a single line?

Comment: you can use `Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 2).Rows.Group` , it will group 3 rows together in a `For` loop on `i`

Comment: @TimWilkinson Like selecting rows, going into DATA -> Group

Comment: @Vinícius Affonso see my answer below, see if you get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will `Group` 3 rows, and since your data is in consecutive rows, you will get 1 huge range of rows grouped together.

If you want to group in a way, that only the first value is visible, and the other 2 are folded, then you actually need to Group only the 2nd and 3rd rows.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GroupEveryNRows()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in Column A
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop from 2nd row till last row with data (assuming the first row has headers)
    For i = 2 To LastRow Step 3
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":A" & i + 2).Rows.Group
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```